# Spring Framework is destroying singletons without any obvious reason

Tags: java, spring

I have a very strange problem:

I have four production servers, all of them configured in the same way and running the same spring application. Since I made a huge refactoring of the app, two of those four servers are not able to init the application context because of an NPE which is caused by a missing bean which should be autowired, but is null.

I switched logging of org.springframework to debug to see any hints. The first thing I see is that on the two crashing servers I see the following entry:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:488) Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'creditServiceImpl': [payPalService, payPalRecurringQueueService]
```

After this entry there are 12 more entries destroying single beans, then one entry destroying all of the remaining beans:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:433) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3085e275: defining beans [[...lots of beans...]]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Afterwards hibernate session is closed, everything is closed down and the only error I get is:

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:307) Context initialization failed
```

I don´t understand why spring is destroying all beans without any error before the destruction. Does anybody know how I can isolate the problem? Building back the app to a point where everything was working fine is not an option because too many changes which all have to take place in one commit.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: After setting the logging to trace, I found out this happens because of circular dependencies and a NPE afterwards, the ERROR is just logged after the destruction of the context which confused me a lot.

I am still confused because the Problem is just on 2 of the 4 servers, but it seems that the order of initializing the beans is different from one server to the other (which confuses me as well)

Comment: Usually the beans are destroyed in the process of shutting down the spring application. I bet that the actual error that makes your app crash is just not displayed in the log files

Comment: This typically happens when there is an error initializing the spring context. As @Funtik pointed, there must another exception leading to this.

Comment: You might want to enable `TRACE` logging to get (probably massive) more information. Also check your server log (not only the application log) to see if there are errors.